# Why does my trigger always insert zero value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am rather confused, because my trigger in SQL Server cannot insert the value what I expected it would. The situation is as follows :

- I have `transaction` table which can have two types of transactions in it - `saldo` and `buy`. If it is `saldo`, the trigger in `transaction` table will insert the amount of the transaction total to `saldo` table, but with `Debit` in its `saldo_type` field.
- So if the case in `transaction` table is `buy`, the same amount will be inserted in `saldo` table, but with `credit` in its `saldo_type` field.

What confuses me is that the trigger will only insert the correct amount of value if the situation is `saldo`, but not if the situation is `buy`

What did I do wrong? Here is the code:

```
declare @last_saldo int
declare @transaction_ammount int

set @last_saldo = (select sum(saldo_ammount) from saldo)
if @last_saldo is null set @last_saldo=0

set @transaction_ammount = (select transaction_ammount from inserted)
IF (select transaction_type from inserted) = 'Saldo'
begin
/* this will insert correct amount */
INSERT INTO saldo
    (id_transaction,transaction_type,saldo_ammount,saldo)
SELECT id_transaction,'Debit',@transaction_ammount,@last_saldo + @transaction_ammount
FROM inserted
RETURN 
END else IF (select transaction_type from inserted)='Buy'
begin
    /* this will not insert the correct ammount. It will always zero! */
INSERT INTO saldo
    (id_transaction,transaction_type,saldo_ammount,saldo)
SELECT id_transaction,'Credit',@transction_ammount,(@last_saldo - @transaction_ammount)
FROM inserted
RETURN 
END
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: OK, first of all - it's spelled "amount" with just one "m" - you consistently misspell it with two "mm". Second: the `Inserted` table can hold **more than one row** - however, your code only ever assumes a single entry in that `Inserted` column - you need to fix that!

Comment: :) thanks for the editing of the mistyped variable. Actually, the code was in Bahasa Indonesia, so before pasted it here, I think it should be better if I translate it. Many thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can refactor your trigger to be a bit simpler:

```
declare @last_saldo int

select @last_saldo = ISNULL(sum(saldo_ammount),0)
 from saldo

INSERT INTO saldo
        (id_transaction,transaction_type,saldo_ammount,saldo)

    SELECT id_transaction,
           CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Saldo' 
             THEN 'Debit'
             ELSE 'Credit' 
           END,
           transaction_ammount,
           CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'Saldo' 
             THEN (@last_saldo + transaction_ammount)
             ELSE (@last_saldo - transaction_ammount)
           END
    FROM inserted
RETURN
```

Is the problem of zero solved with this code? If not, determine what `@last_saldo` and `transaction_ammount` values are. That'll lead you to the root of your problem.

Caveat: be aware that `inserted` can have more than one row!

Comment: :) Many thanks for rewriting my trigger. This is my first time in using MS SQL trigger, I use to do trigger in My SQL before. I apply your trigger here, and the result is the same. But.. after I inspect the code, it turn out that, I insert 0 for the transaction ammount, but then I updated it to the correct ammount. And because my trigger only handled INSERT even, ... well, you know the error that happened... :)
Many thanks for this. I accepted is the answer, and I learn a lot by comparing my first trigger, and your trigger Code. Perfect!

Comment: I just know that inserted can have more than one row. If it's, to make the trigger bullet proof, what will be the modification?thanks

Comment: @swdev: This solution seems to handle multiple rows very well, and the caution about multiple rows in `inserted` at the end of this answer is simply meant for you as a general reminder. That is, every time you are writing a trigger in SQL Server, remember to always treat the 'magic' tables `inserted` and `deleted` as having more than one row.